# error cloudify bootstrap on openstack : no route to host

Tags: ssh, openstack, cloudify

I am getting the following error when I try to bootstrap cloudify 3.4 on openstack:

```
Task failed  'fabrik_plugin.task.run_script-> low level socket error
connecting to host 172.16.x.x on port 22 : no route to host '
```

PS: I am using `centos 7. image (.qcow2)`

I launched an instance with the same image independently of cloudify and I could access it via ssh without any problem

Any idea what does the error mean? And how could I solve it?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: When you launched the instance independently, did you also assign it with a floating IP? if yes, was it a floating IP of the same mask? (172.16.x.x)

Comment: yes the floating ip  was of  the same mask..
But the problem may be caused by the teradown of cloudify .
I have checked the log of the neutron-l3-agent  and neutron-dhcp-agent,it shows that l3 agent can not remove the router because the namespace does not exist .In reality the router is already deleted and I have checked it via  OpenStack CLI  and  OpenStack dashbord.